# Spring OAuth2: can't get additional information from ClientDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am using OAuth2 with Spring Security.
My authentication manager configures client via database: `clients.jdbc(dataSource());`

Everything works, but when requesting a token, I get an exception:

```
2017-04-28 11:14:39.656  WARN 1200 --- [io-8096-exec-10] o.s.s.o.p.c.JdbcClientDetailsService     : Could not decode JSON for additional information: BaseClientDetails [clientId=myclientid, clientSecret=mysecret, scope=[myscope], resourceIds=[], authorizedGrantTypes=[authorization_code, refresh_token], registeredRedirectUris=null, authorities=[], accessTokenValiditySeconds=36000, refreshTokenValiditySeconds=36000, additionalInformation={}]
```

with trace:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.StringReader@557a138f; line: 1, column: 2]
...
...
```

where the column `additional_information` (`varchar(4096)`) in table `client_details` is "asdf" for this entry.

I also tried to change the type of `additional_information` from `String` to `Map<String, Object>` and inserting a string by putting and getting it into the map with the key 'info'. After this, I get the same error, with different trace:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'asdf': was expecting at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3e8a7a77; line: 1, column: 21]
...
...
```

How can I include `additional_information` into my token?

Comment: The `additional_information` must be a JSON string of a `Map<String, Object>` in database.

Comment: Magic! You're THE man! Must be in my database: `{"systemInfo":"Atlas System"}`

Comment: I too added {"systemInfo":"CompanyName System"} into oauth_client_detail table's additional_information column. It worked for me. Thanks.